# How to exclude .php files from being watched by laravel mix

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I'm building a SPA application with laravel, and using laravel mix mostly for frontend files compilation. After launch "yarn run hot", I would like to exclude from being watched server side files (.php), becasuse every time I make a change in the backend, the whole page is reloaded. Even, after the latest windows update, doing a simple ajax call to the server could triger a "[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers..." event in my "yarn run hot" console.

I suppose that excluding .php files from being watched by laravel mix would help me, but I don't know how. Perhaps it is a webpack configuration....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default BrowserSync configuration file in Laravel Mix includes certain paths to be watched, which includes some PHP files.

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/v2.1/src/components/Browsersync.js#L46-L51

You can override individual configuration options by passing an object to the `mix.browserSync(...)` method

```
mix.browserSync({
    proxy: '...',
    files: [ 'public/js/**/*.js', 'public/css/**/*.css' ],
})
```